# mongorestore filter ISODate gives error

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I have this query

```
mongorestore  --db xxx --collection categories  --filter '{"creation_date": {"$gt": ISODate("2015-06-06T20:00:00Z")}}' /backups/xxx/dump/xxx/xxx.bson
```

And have this error

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:25 of:{"creation_date": {"$gt": ISODate("2015-06-06T20:00:00Z")}}
```

I think mongorestore is not happy with ISODate, any ideas?

Comment: Which version are you using because it changed in version 3.0.0: [**`mongorestore`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#options) removed the `--filter`, `--dbpath`, and the `--noobjcheck` options.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the version for strict mode

I had the same problem then I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/issues/50) that points to this [JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-565) that states, that we can use `{"$date": "2015-06-06T20:00:00Z"}` instead of `ISODate("2015-06-06T20:00:00Z")` so your query should look like this:

```
mongorestore --db xxx --collection categories --filter '{"creation_date": {"$gt": {"$date": "2015-06-06T20:00:00Z"}}}' /backups/xxx/dump/xxx/xxx.bson
```

This feature is [documented in MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_date).